# How to Append/Insert new hidden input into form PHP

Tags: php

I have a form request in different page of my script. Example like this one

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to add a hidden input in my form so it will be like this

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="randomnumber">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How to do this in PHP after page successfully access, and not inside each html, so I can confirm that each form of my page has input hidden id

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="randomnumber">
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Are you looking for a way to add the hidden input after the page has already loaded? What would be the purpose of this?

Comment: Yes, so I don't need to add hidden input on each of my html page, So after user access index.php and there is form inside that, it will insert the new hidden input

Comment: I can add this manually by writing <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="randomnumber"> in html, but I want the hidden input add by PHP side

Comment: That doesn't make sense. "PHP side" outputs the HTML, so there would be no difference between adding it manually to HTML templates or adding it manually to whatever PHP script is using the templates. Is this just to avoid having to manually add it to lots of files?

Comment: Is it possible? If in JQUERY, something like $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="id"/>')

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but still doesn't make sense. You still have to add that JS code to every page where you want to use it. It is no different than adding it directly to your HTML (which is a better option anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way,
In my last code before html show, I have to add this

```
echo '<script>var form_id = document.createElement("input");
form_id.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
form_id.setAttribute("name", "form_id");
form_id.setAttribute("value", "form_id");
document.querySelector("form").appendChild(form_id);</script>';
```

Hope this help other, better than just make sense

Comment: Perhaps you should have explained in your question that you have a single page application.